# How to use Volley to support offline feature using cache? Does it support large JSON storage?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, offline-mode

I am using volley for making server calls to fetch data. But now I want my application to work in offline mode too. So using volley cache is good idea or not  and how to use it ?
Does it support large JSon data storage ?

Comment: I you have not found a working solution, you can refer to my anser at [Android Setup Volley to use from Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-setup-volley-to-use-from-cache/32022946#32022946)

Answer (score 0):

Volley has build in cache feature from Queue object you can pick cache by `calling .getCache().get(url)`

Comment: does it store large JSON cacheing ? and For Creating a offline work flow is it a good approach or any other suggestion ?

Comment: It doesn't mind type, just simple byte array. Another approach would be building database and use volley cache for small items. Mostly it depends from particular application and backend.