# Volley cache always returns null in android

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I want to give offline support in my app and I used volley library to parse data from `jsonobject`. I have learned that volley itself has a fine cache mechanism. I have implemented this code to get data from cache

```
Cache cache = GlobalData.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(Constants.URL_WEATHER_REQUEST + city);
```

but the entry always returns null. I have heard about the headers of the server site and I have tested it using restClient addonn in mozilla which looks like this:

[image: header from the server]

I dont know where is the problem but I always get cache entry null and If I turn the internet on volley parses it as usual. What should I do now?

Comment: Please read more at [Android Setup Volley to use from Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-setup-volley-to-use-from-cache/32022946#32022946)

Comment: I will, but can you explain where is the wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps your server app does not allow caching. You can try `Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);` inside `parseNetworkResponse`

Comment: Have your issue been solved yet?

Comment: Hi @Reyjohn did you find any solution to this problem? I'm facing same. In my previous projects it was working fine, i dont what happened now.

Comment: @NaumanZubair: if your server app supports output caching, `Volley` will automatically cache the response, if your server app does not support, you can refer to my above link.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, its figured out already. :)

Answer (score 1):

Volley doesn't have to use only the url as a cache key.

Call **Request.getCacheKey()** to get the cache key.

```
/**
 * Returns the cache key for this request.  By default, this is the URL.
 */
public String getCacheKey() {
    return mMethod + ":" + mUrl;
}

/**
 * Supported request methods.
 */
public interface Method {
    int DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST = -1;
    int GET = 0;
    int POST = 1;
    int PUT = 2;
    int DELETE = 3;
}
```

[The issue on Github.](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/issues/109)