# Android cache mechanism return multi result

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

in my cache mechanism after add the request to the RequestQueue and try to fetch data from server, my cache method return multi duplicate result from server return json string

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = Globals.getHostAddress() + "/get_latest_video";

items.clear();
CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest(0, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            Log.e("allVideos", jsonString);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(cacheRequest);
```

server return this result:

```
{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8}
```

Cache mechanism return :

```
{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8},{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8}
```

whats my code problem to cache data and using that?

`CacheRequest` class content:

```
public class CacheRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public CacheRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
        if (cacheEntry == null) {
            cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
        }
        final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
        final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
        final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
        cacheEntry.data = response.data;
        cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
        cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
        String headerValue;
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
        return Response.success(response, cacheEntry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED POST:**

```
public class ActivityBootstrap extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @InjectView(R.id.drawer_list)
    ListView drawer_list;

    @InjectView(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout drawer_layout;

    @InjectView(R.id.listView)
    AsymmetricGridView listView;

    private List<DrawerItem> drawer_items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    private List<VideoItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private DrawerAdatper drawer_adatper = null;
    private boolean mDrawerState = false;
    private VideoAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = Globals.getHostAddress() + "/get_latest_video";

        items.clear();
        CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest(0, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    Log.e("allVideos", jsonString);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject video_single_item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int video_id = video_single_item.getInt("id");
                        String video_thumbnail = video_single_item.getString("thumbnail");
                        int colSpan = Math.random() < 0.2f ? 2 : 1;
                        int rowSpan = colSpan;
                        VideoItems item = new VideoItems(colSpan, rowSpan, video_thumbnail,video_id);
                        items.add(item);
                    }
                    setUpListView(items);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(cacheRequest);

    }

    private void setUpListView(List video_array_items) {
        final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new VideoListAdapter(this, video_array_items);
        AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
                new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
        listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
        listView.setRequestedColumnCount(3);
        listView.setAdapter(getNewAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setAllowReordering(true);
        listView.isAllowReordering();
    }

    private AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<?> getNewAdapter() {
        return new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        int video_position = items.get(position).getVideo_id();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBootstrap.this, ActivitySHowVideoDetaile.class);
        intent.putExtra("video_id", video_position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED POST 2)**

Result of `Log.e("allVideos", jsonString);` is :

```
10-28 09:51:46.016 17872-17872/pishguy.ir.asrebidree E/allVideos: [{"id":12,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"},{"id":10,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"}]
10-28 09:51:47.249 17872-17872/pishguy.ir.asrebidree E/allVideos: [{"id":12,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"},{"id":10,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"}]
```

Result of server response i'm test it with browser:

```
[{"id":12,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"},{"id":10,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"}]
```

**UNFORTUNATELY this duplicate result is random(NOT duplicate every time)**

**UPDATE 3:**

```
10-28 13:14:52.322 16129-16129/pishguy.ir.asrebidree E/Test: onCreate called
10-28 13:14:52.513 16129-16129/pishguy.ir.asrebidree E/allVideos: [{"id":12,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"},{"id":10,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"}]
10-28 13:14:53.206 16129-16129/pishguy.ir.asrebidree E/allVideos: [{"id":12,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"},{"id":10,"thumbnail":"1445615983c92d10f1f3ee907150be1fdb8184ca893178682-360p__19106.png"}]
```

Comment: You find the duplicated output at "Log.e("allVideos", jsonString);"? Pls post your logcat

Comment: If you mean `items` list has duplicated items, then I cannot find where you update the list

Comment: @BNK hi sir.yes `{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8},{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8}` is my logcat result,my `items` list is very simple, i'm updated post to review again sir. i think if i have both internet connection and cache data on phone, my result is duplicate.

Comment: @BNK I'm trying to use Cache without using database to retrieve data from that and parse again, Thanks

Comment: It's strange, my project does not get duplicated output. Can you post your full logcat info? If it's `{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":8},{"id":12,"channel_id":7,"category_id":‌​8}` I think the line `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);` with throw exception because jsonString is not a json array

Comment: @BNK Post Updated sir. please review that, Thanks a lot

Comment: Try changing `cacheHitButRefreshed ` such as `final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 10 * 60 * 1000;` and check.

Comment: @BNK oh no sir. dont resolve sir. i get duplicate result in random time

Comment: Put `Log.e("Test", "onCreate called");` right below `String url = Globals.getHostAddress() + "/get_latest_video";`, I guess the activity called twice.

Comment: @BNK post updated sir as UPDATE 3 title. activity only call once, :(

Comment: If you have control over server-side app, pls use logging at it to check if the client app sent request twice or not.

Comment: @BNK ok sir. please let me to check that, thanks

Comment: If it received two requests, try setRetryPolicy for your volley request, perhaps you can increase timeout value. Goodluck, see you later.

Comment: @BNK i think problem solved, please let me to test as an long time

Comment: If you have found the solution, pls post it as an answer :)

Comment: Hi! If the response header from the server has the following `Cache-Control → max-age=600`, you don't need to use `CacheRequest` because `Volley` will cache when getting that `Cache-Control` header. You can try another new project.

Comment: @BNK by default and using `CacheRequest` my cache dont refresh if connection is true, cache must be updated if internet connection is true and data changed on server, how to refresh cache if data is updated? Thanks

Comment: @BNK my server `Cache-Control` is `max-age=600, no-cache` can i remove `CacheRequest` and using volley by default such as `StringRequest` or `JsonObjectRequest`?

Comment: For refresh, I think you can find in Cache.java `/** True if a refresh is needed from the original data source. */
        public boolean refreshNeeded() {
            return this.softTtl < System.currentTimeMillis();
        }`, you can update or make `softTtl` smaller or even 0 of course you must check internet connection available

Comment: For `Cache-Control`, set `max-age=600` without `no-cache` since inside `parseCacheHeaders` you will find `if (token.equals("no-cache") || token.equals("no-store")) {
                    return null;
                } else if (token.startsWith("max-age=")) {
                    try {
                        maxAge = Long.parseLong(token.substring(8));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } `

Comment: I suggest that you get Google's official volley from here `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley` to view more details. Goodluck

Comment: Can you tell me that duplication fixed yet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93650/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-bnk).

Comment: @BNK no sir, not fixed yet. i can not find any solution about this problem :(

Comment: Have you put logging in server app yet? It displayed 1 or 2 requests?

Comment: @BNK in server side only call once request

Comment: Ok, if your server supports output caching (remove `no-cache`), try using a JsonArrayRequest instead of CacheRequest to check if duplicate happens or not

Answer (score 0):

Because I have commented too many lines and I cannot re-produce "duplication behavior" as your current issue, so I post my answer here, hope this helps!

Inside `CacheDispatcher` class, you will find the following:

```
                if (!entry.refreshNeeded()) {
                    // Completely unexpired cache hit. Just deliver the response.
                    mDelivery.postResponse(request, response);
                } else {
                    // Soft-expired cache hit. We can deliver the cached response,
                    // but we need to also send the request to the network for
                    // refreshing.
                    request.addMarker("cache-hit-refresh-needed");
                    request.setCacheEntry(entry);

                    // Mark the response as intermediate.
                    response.intermediate = true;

                    // Post the intermediate response back to the user and have
                    // the delivery then forward the request along to the network.
                    mDelivery.postResponse(request, response, new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mNetworkQueue.put(request);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // Not much we can do about this.
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

IMO, it is possible the `softTtl` that is causing this duplication behavior.

I suggest that you use the following line to setRetryPolicy for your request:

```
cacheRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(cacheRequest);
```

Comment: Have you tried setRetryPolicy yet? About my project, I cannot post right now because I'm on mobile :)

Comment: As commented above, suggest that you get Google's official volley from here git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley to view more details.

Comment: no sir. i'm change server response header and set cache to that. after that i'm remove `cacheRequest`, i think problem solved and i dont have duplicate result

Comment: Ok, when you have free time, I think you can test `cacheRequest` with that `setRetryPolicy` to see if it can fix or not.

Comment: i'm testing that sir. using that i hae duplicate result :(

Comment: setRetryPolicy with the second para is 0?

Comment: thanks sir. by your sample my problem solved, i'm using header cache and now how to renew cache if i have internet connection?

Comment: I have not tried checking internet connection yet, however, as I commented in your question above, 
 
For refresh, I think you can find in Cache.java `/** True if a refresh is needed from the original data source. */ public boolean refreshNeeded() { return this.softTtl < System.currentTimeMillis(); }`, you can update or make softTtl smaller or even 0 of course you must check internet connection available