# Volley won't cache my requests

Tags: android, .htaccess, android-volley

I am trying to cache data for offline usage without success. Below is my work so far.

```
  //fetch news details
private void FetchHeadline(){

    showDialog();
    btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // We first check for cached request
Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
Entry entry = cache.get(NEWS_URL);
if (entry != null) {
    Log.e("", "babaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    // fetch the data from cache
    try {
        String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
        try {
            parseJsonFeed(new JSONArray(data));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} else {

    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    JsonArrayRequest jsonReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
            NEWS_URL + dbHelper.getAuth().getString(0), new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
            if (response != null) {
                parseJsonFeed(response);
            }
            hideDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hideDialog();
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + error.getMessage());

            try {
                if (error.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found")){
                    moveToLoginActivity();}
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    });
    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}
```

I added the following to my `.htaccess` with no success

```
    <IfModule headers_module>
    # 1 Month for most static assets
    <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=36000, public"
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Didn't solve my problem

Comment: Did you read the answer? Does the server have the cache control header?

Comment: The server returned this: `Cache-Control →private, must-revalidate, max-age=36000, public`

Comment: Try debugging, set breakpoint at `// Cache-Control takes precedence over an Expires header, even if both exist and Expires
        // is more restrictive.
        if (hasCacheControl) {` inside `parseCacheHeaders` method of `HttpHeaderParser.java` file

Comment: Okay, so if you are making a volley request to any html page or rest api, then you don't have a cache header since you've only cached the file types listed in the htaccess

Comment: It is an API (Laravel) and request goes through the `index.php`. Is it possible to specify some routes (e.g http://myserver.com/api/v1/cars) instead of the whole `index.php` in the .htaccess file?