# Cannot resolve symbol cacheEntry.lastModified when using cache in volley

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley

I am receiving json data and i want to cache it for offline usage though i encounter this error i am unable to solve.

This is my code on oncreate

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest(0, urlJsonArry, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                textView.setText(jsonObject.toString(5));
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "onResponse:\n\n" + jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "onErrorResponse:\n\n" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(cacheRequest);
```

And the code where the error is

```
private class CacheRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public CacheRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
        if (cacheEntry == null) {
            cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
        }
        final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
        final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
        final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
        cacheEntry.data = response.data;
        cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
        cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
        String headerValue;
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
        if (headerValue != null) {

            /** MY ERROR IS HERE**/

            cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);

            /**up**/
        }
        cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
        return Response.success(response, cacheEntry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

I think am not missing any imports - any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add error logs please?

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör code cannot compile with the error. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-setup-volley-to-use-from-cache/32022946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);` undefined, make sure you use the last version of volley. Check if you don't have any old volley     `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')` anywhere. If yes, remove it and replace it in your gradle with

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```