# Volley library - Cache data vs. Download again

Tags: android, json, android-volley

With Android Volley Library, what is the best way to know if an JSON object (or other data) was modified in an url, and download this data again instead of getting it from cache ? Thanks!

Comment: just add a webservice version get api, you have to check it every time users open app and if version is changed call your other api's. Hope it helps

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-set-up-volley-to-use-from-cache