# how to avoid download redundant data using volley?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley for parsing json data, while searching i come across how to avoid redundant data form URL, does volley has inbuilt function to do  like that or we have to do explicitly like below any help?

```
requestQueue.getCache().invalidate(url,true);
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: there is nothing like redundant data download using volley. You are missing something.

Comment: do you mean that we have to do explicitly for validating data .

Comment: validations are depends upon your business rules. Other then this only data is coming from your url which you are hitting.

Comment: What do you mean redundant data?  Do you mean preventing the server from sending data its already sent?  You need to work that out with the server.  Do you mean caching?  That's built in.  Do you mean a more graphql like object graph approach?  That's a matter for your server's api.

Comment: @QandilTariq so my code is not perform as per requirement

Comment: @GabeSechan i want using caching if server already sent data its avoid to downlaod same data just display the data using caching.

Comment: Please, edit your question to explain better what do you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go through this thread: [caching using volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-set-up-volley-to-use-from-cache?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
Here he is caching the data

Here is some code of caching after getting response:

```
 Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
            if (cacheEntry == null) {
                cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
            }
            final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
            final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
            final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
            cacheEntry.data = response.data;
            cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
            cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
```

Comment: that exactly i want